# How to integrate JsonResult with Ajax forms and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Using MVC4, how would I process the return value of a `JsonResult` action in an Ajax form?

All of the examples I was able to locate deal primarily with an html result (`ActionResult`).

I know this question is poorly framed, missing code and such, but I plan on providing my experience as the answer.  Hopefully between this question and the answer there will be some good content.

Answer (score 1):

In an ASP.net controller (C#) you can return a json result as follows (hope you already know it).

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult MyAction(){
    //this is the most amazing content

    return Json(new
    {
        MyResult = "ok",
        MyData = "This is some string data!"
    });
}
```

Its not clear for me what you expect from the answer or I am not sure whether this is what you need as an answer, but hope it will be helpful.

If you are using jquery ajax, you can access the controller and get the json results it returns.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    URL: "/MyController/MyAction",
    dataType: "text"
})
.success(function(data){
    var dataobj = $.parseJSON(data);
    var result = dataobj.MyResult;
    var msg = dataobj.MyData;
});
```

When you are using `return new Json();` the server response is of ContentType **application/json**. But, to use Jquery's parseJSON function correctly, you need to pass the json to the function as a string, otherwise it do not parse it correctly. So, to get the json result as a string or 'text' you need to add `dataType: "text"` as an option to `$.ajax{}`. Then the server returns its response as plain text and you can parse json using jquery's `parseJSON` function. It will return a dynamically created object which includes data returned as json. So you can access those data using the names included in the json string.

Hope this will be helpful somewhat.

Comment: Deepal, thank you for the answer!  I was not expecting anyone to spend any time on this - as I mentioned, I provided my own answer.  This is just a method of sharing my experience with the community.  But thank you very much for the input!

Answer (score 0):

So most examples/tutorials on the web will instruct you to return a view via your `HttpPost` action method.  When doing this you would set the 'UpdateTargetId' and `InsertionMode` properties on the [`AjaxOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) object.

But if you want to return *data* and work with it via javascript, the above method falls short.
Rather, you will need to set the [`OnSuccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onsuccess%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method of the [`AjaxOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) object.

As you can see from the documentation, `OnSuccess` contains zero helpful information.  To use it correctly you need to provide the name of a javascript function available on the current page.  This will be used callback-style so make sure you use the appropriate syntax for your use case.

Here's a little demonstration:

### Controller methods:

```
<HttpGet>
Function AjaxIndex() As ActionResult

    Dim model As AjaxFormModel = New AjaxFormModel
    ' AjaxFormModel is a custom class.  Architect it as you see fit.

    Return View(model)

End Function

<HttpPost>
Function AjaxIndex(ByVal model As AjaxFormModel) As JsonResult

    Dim result As AjaxFormResult = Nothing    
    ' AjaxFormResult is a custom class.  Fill it in with properties that make sense for you.  I personally include .MessageType and .Payload properties.

    ' TODO: be sure you spin up a new object to pass to the `JsonResult`.

    Return New JsonResult With {.Data = result, .JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet}

End Function
```

### Html

```
Using Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxIndex", "Bootstrap",
                     routeValues:=Nothing,
                     ajaxOptions:=New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                        .OnSuccess = "updateAjaxForm"},
                     htmlAttributes:=Nothing)
    @<text>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="UnknownError_message">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="Name" />
                <div id="Name_message"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </text>
End Using
```

### javascript / jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateAjaxForm(data) {
        //data is a fully reconstituted javascript object at this point.  Thank you MVC!
        var messageElement = $('#UnknownError_message');

        switch (data.MessageType) {
            case 0:         //  Error message
                messageElement.html('Error: ' + data.Message);
                break;

            case 1:     //  Textual message
                messageElement.html('Info: ' + data.Message);
                break;

            default:
                messageElement.html('Unforseen Error.');
        }
    }
</script>
```